# ValueError: Could not interpret initializer identifier: 0.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text-classification

I got the following error related to the value of the dropout ratio. I am trying to train with a capsnet algorithm. please help.

```
File "codes/train.py", line 40, in <module>
    text_capsnet.train()
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/DossierT/Application2/text-capsule-network-master/codes/models/text_capsnet.py", line 49, in train
    model = text_layer.get_model(self, summary=True)
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/DossierT/Application2/text-capsule-network-master/codes/models/text_layer.py", line 134, in get_model
    embedding = layers.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embedding_size,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/embeddings.py", line 123, in __init__
    self.embeddings_initializer = initializers.get(embeddings_initializer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/initializers/__init__.py", line 161, in get
    raise ValueError('Could not interpret initializer identifier: ' +
ValueError: Could not interpret initializer identifier: 0.5
```

Comment: Please include the whole training code in order to check for the problem.

Comment: Looks like you should give a string identifier as parameter somewhere but you gave a float instead.